# Permission Error while deleting a django file

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to add a view that deletes files(videos) but it seems that there is something wrong with my form because I am getting a ValueError("The view startup_home.views.delete_video didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead").

views.py

```
    def delete_video(request, video_id):
              delete_v = get_object_or_404(Post, id=video_id)
              delete_v.delete()
              return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

models.py

```
    class Post(models.Model):
        text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        video = models.FileField(upload_to='clips', null=True, blank=True)
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='imageuser', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='username')

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.text)

    @receiver(models.signals.post_delete, sender=Post)
       def auto_delete_file_on_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
       if instance.video:
           if os.path.isfile(instance.video.path):
               os.remove(instance.video.path)
```

urls.py

```
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.home, name='home'),
        path('upload', views.upload, name='upload'),
        path('video/<int:video_id>/', views.delete_video, name='delete_video'),
    ]
```

home.html

```
    {% if content.video %}
        <div class="float-right">
            <form action="video/{{ content.id }}" action="post">
                <button type="submit">Delete</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: What if `form.is_valid()` is `False`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem if form.is_valid() is False returns a ValueError the same one that is on the question description. I just moved 4 spaces to the left the else because that way it doesnt return any error but still doesnt remove the file

Comment: exactly that is what I mean, you need to return something in that case as well, for example render the page again (you can see the errors with `print(form.errors)`).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem so the else should return to its original position with `print(form.errors)` right?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I just edited my views.py but it doesnt show erros

Comment: I am reading some questions and they say that a @reciever should be added to the models but I already tried that and it returns a winpermission error.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Can you check my question? I just updated it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your form code first method is **POST**

```
#In Template
<form action="{% url 'appName:viewName' content.pk %}" method="post">
   ....
</form>
```

Where write appName:viewName like this is a good way of practice

```
# In urls.py
app_name = 'appName'
urlpatterns = [
    path('video/<int:pk>/', views.delete_video, name='viewName'),
]
```

Comment: Now I am getting a `NoReverseMatch at / 'startup_home' is not a registered namespace`. Btw startup_home is the appname and on the main urls.py the appname is called by `path('', include('startup_home.urls')),`.

Comment: Why you not using method="post" instead of action="post"